# How to make BorderThickness, BorderBrush values propagate to all children using XAML

Tags: wpf

In my `Window` if I set `FontFamily`, `FontSize` properties in `XAML` code. They affect all the children. All the controls now have same FontFamily, and FontSize. But if I set `BorderThickness`, `BorderBrush` likewise, only my `Window` gets affected. Rest of child controls don't take any effect.

I want same propagation in all my child control of the Window with `BorderThickness` and `BorderColor` properties like with `FontFamily` and `FontSize`.

Eg;

```
<Window
   ...        
 FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="24">

    <Canvas Margin="50" Background="Wheat">
        <Grid Margin="15" Background="AliceBlue">
            <Button Margin="5" Content="Press"/>
        </Grid>
        <Label Canvas.Left="178" Canvas.Top="10" Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="some text"/>
        </Label>
        <Border Canvas.Left="62" Canvas.Top="128"  Background="Azure" Height="68" Width="181">
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Margin="10,10,16,22"/>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>

</Window>
```

The above piece of code will have all the controls displaying in 'Segoe Print' font with font-size of 24.

But if I set BorderThickness and BorderBrush in my Window tag, only Window gets affected and not all the children.

I can achieve this effect using code by handling `Loaded event` of the Window, using `Binding`, and of course using global `Style` targetting `Border`. But I want to do it without them, as I want the property to get propagated automatically as mentioned above.

**Desired effect** : 
The moment I drag a Control onto my Designer surface, the dragged Control should update its BorderThickness and BorderBrush properties in accordance with that set in Window. If it is not possible with default behavior, then how can I at least achieve this effect of setting a property in window and let all children react to it.

**Note** : I don't want to use a `Style`, but want to utilize `property value inheritance`. [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.basevaluesource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just set a style for `TargetType=Border` in the Window or App resources. Don't put a Key on it.

Comment: @Brannon you dont do it for FontStyle etc.

Comment: Use a source code browser and look at the declarations of FontStyle vs BorderBrush. You will see they are different. The latter is a standard dependency property. It is tied directly to the type of control that declares it.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan if I recall correctly, `FontStyle` etc affects the `TextElement` object which is not actually a Control and has special rules, while `Border` properties only affect the `Border` control. The solution here would be as Brannon said to use an implicit Style. You can set the Style's scope by what `.Resources` you place it in, so if you place it in this `<Window.Resources>` it will only apply to this Window.

Comment: That won't work without a Style, because (in contrast to FontFamily etc.) the BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties don't support value inheritance. The `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` flag is not set in their declarations.

Comment: @Clemens I want to do it without style. I want to mimic exactly same behavior like with FontSize anyhow.

Comment: You don't *want* to use a style.  Then contact Microsoft and tell them how you want the product work.

Comment: @Frisbee   I want to achieve same effect ie; setting a property in Window tag and all the children should react to it.

Comment: @Rachel If that is not possible by default because of the way properties are declared. How can I at least mimic this effect of setting a property in window and all child react to it.

Comment: @Clemens Plz see my updated question at the end.

Comment: And I want a pony.  If you don't *want* to use a style that is your problem.

Comment: @Frisbee If it is not possible with default behavior, then how can I at least achieve this effect of setting a property in window and let all children react to it.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I suppose you could write a custom template for `Border` that checks further up the Visual Tree to see if it should inherit those properties from anywhere... Or you could write a custom DependencyProperty for FrameworkElement that does get inherited, and if applied to a Border object sets the Border properties. A Style would still be preferred though :)

Comment: @Rachel I am ok with both default/custom properties. But I want this parent to child propagation. I want to do it using property-value-inheritance, be it with either default properties or we need to write a custom property. See my updated question.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I would suggest a Custom Dependency Property then. I don't have time to write a full example, however I've written custom DPs before that modify the properties of the base object, like [this](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/), so you could probably use that as an example. You'd have to ensure the DP is for a shared base class (FrameworkElement probably), you turn on inheritance, and when the property changes you check if the object it's applied to is a Border, and if so apply the property values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally achieved what I was trying to achieve. See the code below. Set the two attached properties in Window, and now if you drag controls on the designer, and those controls expose border related properties, changes are visible immediately.

```
<Window ...
   local:InheritableProps.BorderThickness="5.0"
   local:InheritableProps.BorderBrush="Yellow"
>

    <Canvas Margin="50" Background="Wheat">
        <Border Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="103" Width="75">
            <Button Content="Button" Height="22" Margin="5"/>  
        </Border>
        <Label Canvas.Left="177" Canvas.Top="84" Height="55" Width="143">
            <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="120"/>
        </Label>
    </Canvas>

</Window>
```

I wrote two Attached Properties, similar to TextElement.FontSize. And to enable PropertyValueInheritance, I have used the  `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` option. In corresponding PropertyChangedHandlers, I check if the Object exposes border properties, then change these using `SetCurrentValue` method. Direct assignment, or using `SetValue` method will change the local values. Local values have the highest precedence, here we are trying for property value inheritance only.

```
public class InheritableProps : DependencyObject
{
    public static Thickness GetBorderThickness(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Thickness)obj.GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBorderThickness(DependencyObject obj, Thickness value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BorderThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BorderThickness", typeof(Thickness), typeof(InheritableProps),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(BorderThicknessCallback),
                        null));

    public static SolidColorBrush GetBorderBrush(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (SolidColorBrush)obj.GetValue(BorderBrushProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBorderBrush(DependencyObject obj, SolidColorBrush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BorderBrushProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BorderBrush.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BorderBrush", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(InheritableProps),
                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, 
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(BorderBrushCallback),
                        null));

    private static void BorderBrushCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BorderBrush > " + d.ToString());

        Type type = d.GetType();
        PropertyInfo borderBrushPropInfo = type.GetProperty("BorderBrush");
        PropertyInfo borderThicknessPropInfo = type.GetProperty("BorderThickness");

        if (borderBrushPropInfo != null && borderThicknessPropInfo !=null)
        {
            d.SetCurrentValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, e.NewValue);

            /* This will set the local value which has highest precedence*/
            //borderBrushPropInfo.SetValue(d, e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    private static void BorderThicknessCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BorderThickness > " + d.ToString());

        Type type = d.GetType();
        PropertyInfo borderBrushPropInfo = type.GetProperty("BorderBrush");
        PropertyInfo borderThicknessPropInfo = type.GetProperty("BorderThickness");

        if (borderBrushPropInfo != null && borderThicknessPropInfo != null)
        {
            d.SetCurrentValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, e.NewValue);

            /* This will set the local value which has highest precedence*/
            //borderThicknessPropInfo.SetValue(d, e.NewValue);                
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: @Rachel plz see the answer

Comment: @Frisbee plz see the answer

Comment: @Clemens plz see the answer

Comment: @Brannon plz see the answer

Answer (score -1):

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SteelBlue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3,2.7,3,2.7" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
        </Style>
```

Comment: I know I can do this. But I want to achieve the effect of setting `some` property (default/custom) in `Window` which gets propagated to all the children.

Comment: I dont want style but property value getting inherited.

Comment: @Frisbee If it is not possible with default behavior, then how can I at least achieve this effect of setting a property in window and let all children react to it.